# Process of a TV network forming a schedule and sending out a broadcast?

Tags: production

How does a TV network, such as TNT or Nickelodeon, collate TV shows into a schedule of a day and send out a broadcast that is sent to cable/satellite companies?

Is the broadcast left unattended once it has been set?

Comment: I can tell you the second part; No.  When a signal goes down or there is trouble with the relay, someone has to act to fix it.  So, it can't just be left unattended.

Comment: Meetings. Lots of meetings.

Answer (score 2):

For commercial television, the goal is actually to get commercials aired, with the programming being filler to get viewers to watch the ads.

Typically, the programming is done by what is usually known as the "traffic department" based on scheduled programs, advertising costs, advertisers, etc. There is an entire class of software to assist with this.

Once the schedule for the day has been defined, it is imported into a broadcast automation system which controls scheduled play out - typically from video servers and live feeds, but once upon a time from videotape.

The whole process is overseen at all times by broadcast operators who can step in to fix problems like corrupted commercials, broken live feeds, etc, or mismatches in data between the traffic system database of material durations and what is actually stored on the video servers.

For live events, there will also be one or more producers saying when to go to commercial, which view to show, etc.